# Returning select option value when editing in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to edit a course. Now there is a drop down select field where you choose the program that course belongs to. I want to be able to return the program to the select field when i click on the edit button. Right now i am getting a `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` error when i click on the edit button. How can i fix this and be able to get the value into the select field?

My code:

**blade snippet**

```
 {!! Form::open(['action'=>['CoursesController@update', $course->id], 'method'=>'POST']) !!}
    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
       {{Form::label('program_code', 'Program Code')}}
       <div class="col-md-4">
          {!! Form::select('program_code', $course->program_code, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
       {{Form::label('course_code', 'Course Code')}}
       <div class="col-md-4">
          {{Form::text('course_code',$course->course_code,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Course Code'])}}
       </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
     {{Form::label('course_name', 'Course Name')}}
     <div class="col-md-4">
        {{Form::text('course_name',$course->course_name,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Course Name'])}}
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
     {{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
     {{Form::submit('Add Program', ['class'=>'btn btn-success'])}}
  </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Course;
use App\Program;

class CoursesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $courses = Course::all();
        return view('courses.index')->with('courses', $courses);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        // $programs = Program::all();
        // return view('courses.create')->with('programs', $programs);

        $programs = Program::all();
        $select = [];
        foreach($programs as $program){
            $select[$program->program_code] = $program->program_name;
        }
        return view('courses.create', compact(['programs','select']));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'program_code' => 'required',
            'course_code' => 'required',
            'course_name' => 'required'
        ]);

        $course = new Course;
        $course->program_code = $request->input('program_code');
        $course->course_code = $request->input('course_code');
        $course->course_name = $request->input('course_name');
        $course->save();

        return redirect('/home/courses')->with('success', 'Course Successfully addded!');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $course = Course::find($id);
        return view('courses.edit')->with('course', $course);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'program_code' => 'required',
            'course_code' => 'required',
            'course_name' => 'required'
        ]);

        $course = Course::find($id);
        $course->program_code = $request->input('program_code');
        $course->course_code = $request->input('course_code');
        $course->course_name = $request->input('course_name');
        $course->save();

        return redirect('/home/courses')->with('success', 'Course Successfully updated!');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: the second argument to `select` is the list, not the selected value  https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html#drop-down-lists ... you aren't passing a list to be used for the select to your view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Forms select method parameter sequence is

1. name
2. list of items
3. default select value
4. extra parameters

You need to change code from

```
{!! Form::select('program_code', $course->program_code, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

to

```
{!! Form::select('program_code',["Option1","Option2","Option3",..], $course->program_code, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```